# How are the values for x and y axis chosen for histogram plots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I'm plotting a histogram plot, but I don't understand the x and y axis values. How do they get their values?

```
x=np.random.randint(0,100,100)
x=pd.DataFrame(x)
means=[]
for i in range(0,10000):
    means.append(x[0].sample(10).mean())
plt.hist(means)
```

Help me in analysing this visual.
[image: the generated histogram]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x=np.random.randint(0,100,100)
x=pd.DataFrame(x)
means=[]
for i in range(0,10000):
    means.append(x[0].sample(10).mean())
plt.hist(means)
plt.show()
```

This produces:[image]

Your means have values such as 32.8, 19.4, 73.9, 54.3, etc. (10000 of this kind of values). The histogram divides these 10000 numbers into groups defined by ranges. For example, one bin with the means smaller than 13, another bin with the values between 13 and 19, ... .  The values for the bins are visible on the x-axis.  On the y-axis is shown how many values are inside each bin. In this case there are about 2700 in the largest one (around x-value 50).

The values chosen on the x-axis are calculated automatically depending on your data. The algorithm guesses something what's suitable in a general situation. If you want to, you can give your own bins as extra parameter. The y-axis just comes from counting, so there is less to choose.

Answer (score 0):

first your dataset is generated as random 100 numbers.

in this line,you take the random sample of 10 numbers from the 0th column and get the mean.so it will be a single number.

```
means.append(x[0].sample(10).mean())
```

take a look at this example

[image]

here i have plot a one value instead of looping over to understand easily. In this example random mean is 32. it is taken as X axis value and according to the [matplotlib documentation if you don't specify a bin,it will take default bins as 10](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).As you can see there are two arrays printed out above the plot.second array is bins array and first array is The values of the histogram bins. [check the return part of the documentation.](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html). Y axis is number of occurrences of the values within a bin.

Answer (score 0):

You've created the means list of 10000 values.
The x-axis of the histogram corresponds to each value of this means list.
The y-axis counts the frequency of those x-values, within the width of it's rectangle interval.

So, the visual is the distribution of this continuous variable.
And, as you will see, it shows a normal distribution, often called the bell curve

You can have another distribution plot :

```
import seaborn
seaborn.distplot(means)
```